# Matching dictionaries and creating new wb

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets where I want to compare a "code" appearing in the first column of both sheets.

This is sheet1:
[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVUBa.png)

this is sheet2: [sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCQZQ.png)

I want to go through each code on sheet1 and find all the rows on sheet 2 that have the same code and insert the row (from sheet2) into a new wb.

This is how i am creating the dictionaries.

```
iLastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
For iRow = 18 To iLastRow
    sKey = ws1.Cells(iRow, 3)
    If Dict.Exists(sKey) Then
        Dict(sKey) = Dict(sKey) & ";" & iRow ' matched row on sheet 1
    Else
        Dict(sKey) = iRow
    End If
    Debug.Print ((sKey))
Next

Debug.Print ("These are the values in dictionary2")
'' Dictionary broker code sheet 2
iLastRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For iRow = 2 To iLastRow
    sBROKER = ws2.Cells(iRow, 1)
    If Dict.Exists(sBROKER) Then
        dictBROKER(sBROKER) = dictBROKER(sKey) & ";" & iRow ' matched row on sheet 1
    Else
        dictBROKER(sBROKER) = iRow
    End If
    Debug.Print ((sBROKER))
Next
```

the debug print part: [debug.print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BidKu.png)

I hope someone can help me

Comment: Your code does not enter ranges (rows) in the dictionary. It enters only row numbers... You cannot use it for the purpose you declare...

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru.  Do you have a solution to how I can solve this problem then?

Comment: I could help, if I would understand what you want to accomplish, but I confess I don't... Try explaining your code in words. Otherwise, it looks strange for me. It searches the `ws2` values of A:A in dictionary and what should it do? Replacing the existing values? Then, if a match is not found, what  `dictBROKER(sBROKER) = iRow` wants to be? Why do you load the row where a match could not be found?

Comment: What " all the rows on sheet 2 that have the same code" does mean? What "code" do your rows keep? Do you mean 'kode' from the column A:A?

Comment: In sheet1 i have a column (column "C"). In that column i have some values which only appear once(The value is a specific code). For example i have the value 00010 in cell "c18". So 00010 only appears in cell c18 and not later in that column. But in sheet2 00010 can appear many times. What i want to do is make a new wb with all the values that match with the specific value in sheet1. So if c18=00010 i want to take all the 00010 from sheet2(entire row) and insert into a new wb

Comment: How many columns for each row should be processed/copied?

Comment: 5 columns from sheet2. from A:E

Comment: But, first one, starting from C:C, does not have columns to be copied in the merged new workbook? If not, I still do not understand what is to be done...

Comment: Not sure how to explain it further.. sorry

Comment: Let me rephrase: The code will start searching the first sheet. For each code found, it will start searching the second one and all matches will be moved in the new workbook (5 columns). Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what needs to happen

Comment: So, you do not need any dictionary... I do not have time right now, but before leaving the office I will try a piece of code able to do what (I understand) you need. But isn't it possible to not find any match in the second worksheet? If yes, what is to be done?

Comment: Sounds good! Thank you @FaneDuru

Comment: I asked you a clarification question... I cannot start working without perfectly understanding what is to be done.

Comment: Oh sorry. If there is not a match between sheet 1 and sheet 2 it should just go to next row on sheet 1. So basically just skip the rows on sheet 1 that does not have a match on sheet 2

Comment: So, please test the code I posted. You must only take care of adapting it to use your real "SecondSheet" worksheet... I will leave my office in some minutes. If something does not work as you need, I will solve it when I will be at home...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub copyToNewSheets()
 Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, rngC As Range, skey As String
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastCol As Long, iLastRow, jLastRow As Long
 Dim Wb As Workbook, wsNew As Worksheet, k As Long, rngHeader As Range

 Set ws1 = ActiveSheet               'use here your sheet
 Set ws2 = Worksheets("SecondSheet") 'use here your sheet, too
 iLastRow = ws1.cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
 jLastRow = ws2.cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
 Set rngHeader = ws2.Range("A1:E1")

 'Create the new workbook
 Set Wb = Workbooks.Add
 For i = 1 To Wb.Worksheets.count - 1
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       Wb.Sheets(i).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Next i
 
  'for making the code faster:_________________
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  '____________________________________________
  
  lastCol = 5: k = 1
  For i = 18 To iLastRow
    skey = ws1.cells(i, 3).Value
    For j = 2 To jLastRow
        If skey = ws2.Range("A" & j).Value Then
            If rngC Is Nothing Then
                Set rngC = ws2.Range(ws2.Range("A" & j), ws2.cells(j, lastCol))
            Else
                Set rngC = Union(rngC, ws2.Range(ws2.Range("A" & j), ws2.cells(j, lastCol)))
            End If
        End If
    Next j
    If Not rngC Is Nothing Then
        If k = 1 Then
            Set wsNew = Wb.Sheets(k): k = k + 1
        Else
            Set wsNew = Wb.Sheets.Add(After:=Wb.Sheets(k - 1)): k = k + 1
            
        End If
        wsNew.Name = skey
        rngHeader.Copy Destination:=wsNew.Range("A1")
        rngC.Copy Destination:=wsNew.Range("A2")
        Set rngC = Nothing
   End If
 Next i
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  MsgBox "Ready...", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: So it creates a new workbook as it should but it inserts all the values from sheet2 into the same new workbook. So what i need to do is to create a file for each group/specific code.

Comment: so a new workbook for all the 00010 from sheet 2, a new file for 30200 from sheet 2 etc. Does this make sense?

Comment: Did you say anything about that and I missed it? Now I am driving. If yes, I will adapt it whwn I will be at home

Comment: I think that I have tried to explain it. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough in my explanation.

Comment: That is great! I appreciate your help, Thank you! 

Suppose that i want a workbook and not a worksheet for each code, is that hard to change in the code above?

Comment: @lass9509: Not very difficult, but  you must understand the code logic... This is our purpose here. We do not make code for free... We try helping you to learn and understand your code weakness... For now, I will give you a hint: The new workbook will not be created before the loop. It will be created at the end of the loop, receiving the `skey` name and the sheet `Set wsNew = Wb.Sheets(1)`. If you will succeed adapting by yourself, i will give you 10 points notoriety voting the question up. If not, i will help you showing how to do it. But I am positive that you can do it by yourself...

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru. I created a solution, and it is all working as i wanted it to do! 

If Not rngC Is Nothing Then
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsNew = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
        rngHeader.copy Destination:=wsNew.Range("A1")
        rngC.copy Destination:=wsNew.Range("A2")
        Set rngC = Nothing
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wbNew.SaveAs fileName:=skey
        wbNew.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

The i also needed to delete the line: 
'Set Wb = Workbooks.Add
And 
'Wb.Sheets(i).Delete


So thank you again for your help!

Comment: @lass9509: So, you deserve your 10 notoriety points. Now you can vote up the answer you like... :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different approach

```
Sub CopyToNewWorkbook()

    Dim oMasterWS As Worksheet: Set oMasterWS = Sheet3        '<- Change to the sheet that has the codes
    Dim oDataWS As Worksheet: Set oDataWS = Sheet4            '<- Change to sheet where you want to copy row from
    Dim oNewWB As Workbook
    Dim iTRMWS As Long: iTRMWS = oMasterWS.Range("A" & oMasterWS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim iTRDWS As Long
    Dim iC As Long
    Dim oFilterRng As Range
    
    With oDataWS
        
        ' Get Data sheet row count
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        iTRDWS = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        ' Loop through all values in Master sheet
        For iC = 2 To iTRMWS
            
            ' Set filter on Data sheet based on the value from Master sheet
            .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=oMasterWS.Range("A" & iC).Value
            
            ' Set filtered range
            Set oFilterRng = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set oFilterRng = .Range("A2:A" & iTRDWS).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            ' If filtered range is found, copy it to a new workbook
            If Not oFilterRng Is Nothing Then
                Set oNewWB = Workbooks.Add
                oFilterRng.EntireRow.Copy oNewWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
                oNewWB.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & oMasterWS.Range("A" & iC).Value
                oNewWB.Close savechanges:=False
            End If
            
            ' Clear filter
            If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        
        Next
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution! But @FaneDuru provided exactly what i needed which is why I marked his answer as solution to my problem